# Bash code error unexpected syntax error

Tags: bash, awk

I am not sure why i am getting the unexpected syntax '( err

```
#!/bin/bash
DirBogoDict=$1
BogoFilter=/home/nikhilkulkarni/Downloads/bogofilter-1.2.4/src/bogofilter
echo "spam.."

for i in 'cat full/index |fgrep spam |awk -F"/" '{if(NR>1000)print$2"/"$3}'|head -500'
do
        cat $i |$BogoFilter -d $DirBogoDict -M -k 1024 -v
done

echo "ham.."
for i in 'cat full/index | fgrep ham | awk -F"/" '{if(NR>1000)print$2"/"$3}'|head -500'
do
        cat $i |$BogoFilter -d $DirBogoDict -M -k 1024 -v
done
```

Error:

```
./score.bash: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./score.bash: line 7: `for i in 'cat full/index |fgrep spam |awk -F"/" '{if(NR>1000)print$2"/"$3}'|head -500''
```

Comment: Please clean up your code... four leading spaces on each line would create a code block (with the code block separated with two returns). This is super hard to read as is... No offense.

Comment: Could you also paste your exact error that you are receiving?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour This will show you a good way to ask a question and you get a token for it.

Comment: It looks like there is bunch errors with this. A good resource that I use whenever I am troubleshooting my scripts is: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Also don't forget to select an answer below as resolving your issue. This will help future people to find a correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Uh, because you have **massive** syntax errors.

The immediate problem is that you have an unpaired single quote before the `cat` which exposes the Awk script to the shell, which of course cannot parse it as shell script code.

Presumably you want to use backticks instead of single quotes, although you [should actually not read input with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

With a fair bit of refactoring, you might want something like

```
for type in spam ham; do
    awk -F"/" -v type="$type" '$0 ~ type && NR>1000 && i++<500 {
         print $2"/"$3 }' full/index |
    xargs $BogoFilter -d $DirBogoDict -M -k 1024 -v
done
```

This refactors the [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) `cat | grep | awk | head` into a single Awk script, and avoids the silly loop over each output line.  I assume `bogofilter` can read file name arguments; if not, you will need to refactor the `xargs` slightly.  If you can pipe all the files in one go, try

```
... xargs cat | $BogoFilter -d $DirBogoDict -M -k 1024 -v
```

or if you really need to pass in one at a time, maybe

```
... xargs sh -c 'for f; do $BogoFilter -d $DirBogoDict -M -k 1024 -v <"$f"; done' _
```

... in which case you will need to `export` the variables `BogoFilter` and `DirBogoDict` to expose them to the subshell (or just inline them -- why do you need them to be variables in the first place? Putting command names in variables is particularly weird; just update your `PATH` and then simply use the command's name).

In general, if you find yourself typing the same commands more than once, you should think about how to avoid that.  This is called the [DRY principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself).

Comment: Tee hee, we could cheat by passing your `$1` as the `$0` to the subshell.  But this is getting fairly obscure.  `PATH=/home/nikhilkulkarni/Downloads/bogofilter-1.2.4/src/:$PATH; stuff | xargs sh -c 'for f; do bogofilter -d "$0" -M -k 1024 -v <"$f"; done' "$1"`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is due to bad quoting.  The expression whose output you want to loop over should be in [command substitution syntax](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) (`$(...)` or backticks), not single quotes.